# how to convert URI to File Android 10

Tags: android, file, storage, uri

how to get file object from URI OR convert URI to file object in android 10 and above versions.

```
 final File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "read.me");
 Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
```

Comment: The question is: why would you want that? You can use the uri directly.

Comment: some older libraries are not recognized URI, they only want file objects like a retrofit, some image editors, etc.

Comment: i wat to convert uri to file to inputstream

Comment: @Akashkumar you can use answer code to convert URI to file and then use 
new FileInputStream(file); 
for inputstream conversion

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You cannot convert the direct file to URI in android 10 instead of this you can make a copy of the file into your file directory which will help you to get a file object.

```
File f = getFile(getApplicationContext(), uri);
```

The below method provide you file object of URI and also you have a copy of the file in your file directory.

```
    public static File getFile(Context context, Uri uri) throws IOException {
    File destinationFilename = new File(context.getFilesDir().getPath() + File.separatorChar + queryName(context, uri));
    try (InputStream ins = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri)) {
        createFileFromStream(ins, destinationFilename);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Log.e("Save File", ex.getMessage());
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return destinationFilename;
}

public static void createFileFromStream(InputStream ins, File destination) {
    try (OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(destination)) {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
        int length;
        while ((length = ins.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            os.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
        os.flush();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Log.e("Save File", ex.getMessage());
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private static String queryName(Context context, Uri uri) {
    Cursor returnCursor =
            context.getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
    assert returnCursor != null;
    int nameIndex = returnCursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME);
    returnCursor.moveToFirst();
    String name = returnCursor.getString(nameIndex);
    returnCursor.close();
    return name;
}
```

for more detail refer [here](https://androidfortechs.blogspot.com/2020/12/how-to-convert-uri-to-file-android-10.html)

Comment: reference link provided is not working "Sorry, the page you were looking for in this blog does not exist."

Comment: This was exactly what I needed, was able to convert my content Uri to a file to upload as a MultipartBody.Part