# I can't upload image from device to firebase storage (kotlin)

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-storage

i want to upload an image from device to Storage in Firebase. I've already done all like docs but it's give me this error.

```
 E/UploadTask: could not locate file for uploading:file:///content%3A/com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider/-1/1/content%253A%252F%252Fmedia%252Fexternal%252Fimages%252Fmedia%252F31/ORIGINAL/NONE/image%252Fjpeg/446954168
E/StorageException: StorageException has occurred.
    An unknown error occurred, please check the HTTP result code and inner exception for server response.
     Code: -13000 HttpResult: 0
E/StorageException: /content:/com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider/-1/1/content%3A%2F%2Fmedia%2Fexternal%2Fimages%2Fmedia%2F31/ORIGINAL/NONE/image%2Fjpeg/446954168: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: /content:/com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider/-1/1/content%3A%2F%2Fmedia%2Fexternal%2Fimages%2Fmedia%2F31/ORIGINAL/NONE/image%2Fjpeg/446954168: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:492)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:160)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:115)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.openInputStream(ContentResolver.java:1473)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.<init>(UploadTask.java:137)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference.putFile(StorageReference.java:241)
        at com.example.admin_bookmarket.ViewModel.AddItemViewModel.addImagetoDb(AddItemViewModel.kt:29)
        at com.example.admin_bookmarket.ViewModel.AddItemViewModel.addtoDb$lambda-0(AddItemViewModel.kt:19)
        at com.example.admin_bookmarket.ViewModel.AddItemViewModel.lambda$N5o2mCXPU9IS7gghhVKoBmB96Bo(Unknown Source:0)
        at com.example.admin_bookmarket.ViewModel.-$$Lambda$AddItemViewModel$N5o2mCXPU9IS7gghhVKoBmB96Bo.onSuccess(Unknown Source:6)
        at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzn.run(Unknown Source:4)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
     Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
        at libcore.io.Linux.open(Native Method)
        at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.open(ForwardingOs.java:166)
        at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:254)
        at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.open(ForwardingOs.java:166)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$AndroidOs.open(ActivityThread.java:7542)
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:478)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:160) 
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:115) 
        at android.content.ContentResolver.openInputStream(ContentResolver.java:1473) 
        at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.<init>(UploadTask.java:137) 
        at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference.putFile(StorageReference.java:241) 
        at com.example.admin_bookmarket.ViewModel.AddItemViewModel.addImagetoDb(AddItemViewModel.kt:29) 
        at com.example.admin_bookmarket.ViewModel.AddItemViewModel.addtoDb$lambda-0(AddItemViewModel.kt:19) 
        at com.example.admin_bookmarket.ViewModel.AddItemViewModel.lambda$N5o2mCXPU9IS7gghhVKoBmB96Bo(Unknown Source:0) 
        at com.example.admin_bookmarket.ViewModel.-$$Lambda$AddItemViewModel$N5o2mCXPU9IS7gghhVKoBmB96Bo.onSuccess(Unknown Source:6) 
        at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzn.run(Unknown Source:4) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947) 
E/StorageException: StorageException has occurred.
    An unknown error occurred, please check the HTTP result code and inner exception for server response.
     Code: -13000 HttpResult: 0
    /content:/com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider/-1/1/content%3A%2F%2Fmedia%2Fexternal%2Fimages%2Fmedia%2F31/ORIGINAL/NONE/image%2Fjpeg/446954168: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: /content:/com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider/-1/1/content%3A%2F%2Fmedia%2Fexternal%2Fimages%2Fmedia%2F31/ORIGINAL/NONE/image%2Fjpeg/446954168: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:492)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:160)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:115)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.openInputStream(ContentResolver.java:1473)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.<init>(UploadTask.java:137)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference.putFile(StorageReference.java:241)
        at com.example.admin_bookmarket.ViewModel.AddItemViewModel.addImagetoDb(AddItemViewModel.kt:29)
        at com.example.admin_bookmarket.ViewModel.AddItemViewModel.addtoDb$lambda-0(AddItemViewModel.kt:19)
        at com.example.admin_bookmarket.ViewModel.AddItemViewModel.lambda$N5o2mCXPU9IS7gghhVKoBmB96Bo(Unknown Source:0)
        at com.example.admin_bookmarket.ViewModel.-$$Lambda$AddItemViewModel$N5o2mCXPU9IS7gghhVKoBmB96Bo.onSuccess(Unknown Source:6)
        at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzn.run(Unknown Source:4)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
     Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
        at libcore.io.Linux.open(Native Method)
        at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.open(ForwardingOs.java:166)
        at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:254)
        at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.open(ForwardingOs.java:166)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$AndroidOs.open(ActivityThread.java:7542)
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:478)
```

here is my code for get imageUri and call function from viewModel to upload it to Storage.

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == pickImage) {
            imageUri = data?.data
            path = data?.data?.path!!
            binding.idThumbnail.setImageURI(imageUri)
            binding.idTnBackground.setImageURI(imageUri)
            binding.idImgeURL.setText(imageUri.toString(), TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE)
        }
    }

    fun addNewBook()
    {
        if (binding.idCount.text.toString() != "" && binding.idImgeURL.text.toString() != "" && binding.idAuthor.text.toString() != "" &&
            binding.idTitle.text.toString() != "" && binding.idDescription.text.toString() != "" && binding.idPrice.text.toString() != "" &&
            binding.idKind.text.toString() != "")
        {
            newBook =  mutableMapOf("Image" to binding.idImgeURL.text.toString(), "Name" to binding.idTitle.text.toString(),
            "Author" to binding.idAuthor.text.toString(), "Price" to binding.idPrice.text.toString().toDouble().roundToInt(), "rate" to "0".toDouble().roundToInt(),
                "Kind" to binding.idKind.text.toString(), "Counts" to binding.idCount.text.toString().toDouble().roundToInt(), "Description" to binding.idDescription.text.toString())

            viewModel.addtoDb(newBook)

            binding.idCount.setText("", TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE)
            binding.idImgeURL.setText("", TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE)
            binding.idAuthor.setText("", TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE)
            binding.idTitle.setText("", TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE)
            binding.idDescription.setText("", TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE)
            binding.idPrice.setText("", TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE)
            binding.idKind.setText("", TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE)
        }
        Toast.makeText(this, "Add success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
```

below is function which a call above from viewModel to upload it to Storage

```
fun addtoDb(newBook: MutableMap<String, Any>)
    {
        FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("books").add(newBook).addOnSuccessListener {
            val id: String = it.id
            addImagetoDb(Uri.parse(newBook["Image"].toString()), id)
        }
    }

    fun addImagetoDb(imageUri: Uri, id: String)
    {
        var storageRef = Firebase.storage.reference
        var file = Uri.fromFile(File(imageUri.toString()))
        val bookImageRef = storageRef.child("${id}/${file.lastPathSegment}")
        val uploadTask = bookImageRef.putFile(file)
        uploadTask.addOnSuccessListener {
            FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("books").document(id).update("Image", bookImageRef)
        }
    }
```

I already try get "Path" instead "Uri" but it gave me the same Error. (all of that not crash the app though)

I already add below dependencies:

```
 implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:28.1.0')
 implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
 implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore-ktx:23.0.1'
 implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage-ktx'
 implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:20.0.0'
 implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:20.0.0'
```

Comment: The error message is pretty clear I think: "No such file or directory". File does not exist, path is wrong.

Comment: I had another ImageView to load the Uri i get and it display the Image too.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a firebase issue. The problem is clearly mentioned. The file does not exist OR the file is not converted from URI.
some libraries are not supported URI objects or vice versa. The thing is clear due to conversion issue or android storage limitation you are facing this problem.
one bypass way you can use as copy file into a file directory and then use it after that delete from the file directory.
[you can refer to this for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65447194/how-to-convert-uri-to-file-android-10/65447195)

OR

if you are using android 11 and above due to policy change you are facing this
[for detail refer to official document here.](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage)