# Can not get file on android API 29 up

Tags: android, kotlin, file-upload

I can not read a file that I'm saving. I have declared and asking for storage permissions.

```
fun saveImage(bitmap: Bitmap, context: Context): String {
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 29) {
        val values = contentValues()
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.RELATIVE_PATH, "Pictures/" + context.getString(R.string.app_name))
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.IS_PENDING, true)
        // RELATIVE_PATH and IS_PENDING are introduced in API 29.

        val uri: Uri? = context.contentResolver.insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values).also { uri ->
            if (uri != null) {


                if (uri != null) {
                    saveImageToStream(bitmap, context.contentResolver.openOutputStream(uri))
                    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.IS_PENDING, false)
                    context.contentResolver.update(uri, values, null, null)

                }


                //val split = file.path.split(":".toRegex()).toTypedArray() //split the path.
                Log.d(
                    "Tag",
                    "v--- uri.path - ${uri.path}, "
                )

                return uri.path.toString() //assign it to a string(your choice).


            }
        }

    } else { // below API 29 }
}
```

then in onCreate or any other method I want to access that file and show on preview.

```
            val previousPath = """/external/images/media/356""" //preferenceManager.getString(...)
            //val file  = File(path)

            //previewImage.setImageURI(Uri.parse(previousPath))
       val file  = FileUtils().getFile(applicationContext, Uri.parse(previousPath))
                            Log.d("Tag", "Yo --- "+file?.path + " , "+ file?.name)


//  val myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile()
// previewImage.setImageBitmap()
```

But this is always empty. With [this getFile method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65447195/7291498), I get null pointer exception. I need the file to upload to server. How can I get this file?

Comment: `val previousPath = """/external/images/media/356"""` No. You should have saved the whole content scheme of the uri. A content scheme uri starts with "content://". Instead of  return uri.path.toString() you should have used uri.string i think for later use. (dont know kotlin that well).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > val uri: Uri? = context.contentResolver.insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values)

You used that obtained uri to save your file content to storage with:

```
 context.contentResolver.openOutputStream(uri)
```

Now if you wanna read that file use the same uri again. Just use:

```
context.contentResolver.openInputStream(uri)
```

Use the same uri!

Dont mess around with the File class.